# É necessário fechar conexões MongoDB com PyMongo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

Estou trabalhando numa API REST com Python (Flask + MongoDB) e durante o desenvolvimento verifiquei que, em nenhuma parte do código, eu havia liberado os recursos do banco.

Já pesquisei por aí mas não achei nada factível sobre a melhor forma de trabalhar esta abordagem.

Não sei se o MongoDB é autogerenciável quanto a isso, ou se devo, programaticamente, manipular isso. Normalmente em Java ou qualquer outra linguagem, fazendo uso de drivers para os SGDBs ou ORMs, tem-se a preocupação em fechar as conexões com o banco quando este não está mais sendo solicitado pela aplicação.

Por exemplo, minha classe que fornece o método de conexão está assim:

```
from mongoengine import connect
from siava.app.aplicacao.utils.Configuracoes import Configuracoes


class Conexao(object):
    """
    Mantem conexões com o banco de dados
    """

    @classmethod
    def conectar(self):
        config = Configuracoes()

        connect(
            name=config.banco['banco'],
            host=config.banco['host'],
            port=config.banco['porta'],
            username=config.banco['usuario'],
            password=config.banco['senha'])
```

O [mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/) (que encapsula o [PyMongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/)) até possui o método disconnect() mas na documentação não tem nada sobre o uso do mesmo. Talvez seja de uso interno e não faça parte da interface/api de uso dos recursos.

Com isso, fica a dúvida, devo controlar a liberação de recursos do banco ou de alguma forma isso é gerenciado pelo próprio MongoDB, ou até mesmo pelo ODM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um aplicação WEB escalável não deve abrir uma conexão para atender a cada requisição - em vez disso, a prática é ter um conjunto (poll) de conexões ativas que são reutilizadas a cada request web.

Como você está usando Flask  - que reune uma série de abordagens relacionadas a aplicaçẽos escaláveis, ele tem recursos para fazer isso, e fornecer para o código que roda em suas views (inclusive o código chamado por elas), uma instância de conexão desse poll.

Só que se você cria sua conexão "manualmente" como está fazendo - seguindo as instruções apenas do lado do Mongo, sem se preocupar com o ciclo de vida de uma requisição do Flask, nem com sua arquitetura, você não está tirando proveito desses mecanismos.

Assim, não só sua conexão pode "vazar" permanecendo aberta sem ser fechada (é possível que elea seja fechada, se acabam todas as referências à mesma ao final de um request), mas sobretudo, o mais provável é que você esteja usando um monte de recursos (CPU, rede, tempo) para criar uma nova conexão para cada requisição Web. Você não colocou o código que você usa para chamar a criação da conexão - pode ser que você até esteja tentando reciclar conexões entre requisições - nesse caso estaria no caminho certo, mas ainda é uma questão de reinventar a roda.

Tendo dito tudo isso, a forma correta de fazer é pegar algum pacote que já faça a integração do MongoDB com o FLask, tirando proveito de todos os mecanismos do Flask para uso de uma poll de conexões. Por exemplo, o  [flask-pymongo](https://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), ou o próprio [SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/), que tem algum suporte a MongoDB também.

Comment: Entendi, vlw pelas dicas. Vou procurar dar uma estudada nesta questão sobre o tratamento das conexões do lado do Flask. Utilizo o mongoengine como ODM para a camada de abstração e persistência dos documentos, o Flask estou utilizando somente como FW REST pois no Hug (http://www.hug.rest/) tive alguns problemas com captura do POST.